# Implementing a score counter in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to implement a score counter in my Aframe scene, and so far I have [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lumpy-pedestrian?path=index.html:112:46) code but it isn't working. Would someone be able to take a look at the code below and spot the mistake I'm making? Many Thanks. D

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('score counter', {
schema: {
  el: {
    type: 'selector'
  },
  score:{
    type: 'int',
    default: 0
  },

tick: function () {
  var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
  var el1 = this.el;
  var el2 = this.data.el;
  var entity = document.querySelector('#score');
      sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.data.score++;
      this.data.score = 0;
      entity.emit('updateScore');
      AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(entity, 'text.value', "score \n" + this.data.score);   
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tick function happens really often, since it's usually used for drawing. So if you put your code there, your calling it every millisecond or so, and so you're just consuming more and more eventlisteners.

Here is the docs for it:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-a-behavior-with-the-tick-handler

That said, You'll want to put that code in the init function since it only occurs one time.

Also in your code your incrementing the score with `++` but right after your setting the score to zero.

Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with the click on the box?

***Updated:***

Here is a basic working example:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-scoreboard

Simply increment the score and set the new text value.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('score-counter', {
  schema: {
    el: {
      type: 'selector'
    },
    score:{
      type: 'int',
      default: 0
    },
  },

  init: function () {
    var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
    var scoreBoard = document.querySelector('#score');

    sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.data.score++;
      var newScore = 'Score: ' + this.data.score
      scoreBoard.setAttribute('text', 'value',  newScore)
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Noam. I just chopped together some code I had and some other code I found, I dont actually understand a lot of these commands sadly. The aim was first to get a score incrementing by 1 each time a box is clicked and then I wanted to look at that code and work it into one of my if statements cross referencing it with an attribute  value in one of my entities.

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer to give you a basic working example to start with. Make note of the () => function instead of `'click', function...` this give you the ability to access `this.data.score` inside the listener.

Comment: Is there a way to use this score-counter component you wrote inside of a <a-entity tag instead of a <a-scene tag? I'm having trouble getting the box to add numbers when I'm using it within another one of my other components. At first I thought it might be the tick: function () { but it seems to happen with Init: function as well so I figured it had something to do with the <a-scene html reference.

Comment: Should work, here's a slightly modified version on the entity itself.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-scoreboard-entity

Are you going to have multiple boxes/entities using this component? If so, you'll need to modify the score variable to be more global, like window.score instead of this.data.score.