# A-frame score counter with multiple objects

Tags: aframe

I've looked at this answer: [Implementing a score counter in A-Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216250/implementing-a-score-counter-in-a-frame)

... but cannot figure out how to write a similar function that would work for multiple objects, since querySelector only finds the first element.

I'm trying to create a scene with 5-8 objects, and each one can only be clicked once. When an object is clicked, the counter will increment by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Either use querySelectorAll:

```
var targets = querySelectorAll('a-box')`
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {  // Add event listeners... }
```

But **better**, use a container entity that listens to the click events that bubble up.

```
<a-entity listener>
  <a-box data-raycastable></a-box>
  <a-box data-raycastable></a-box>
</a-entity>
<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: [data-raycastable]"></a-entity>
```

Component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('listener', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      if (evt.target.dataset.wasClicked) { return; }
      // evt.target tells you which was clicked.
      evt.target.dataset.wasClicked = true;
      // Score up.
    });
  }
});
```

As a side note, state component is a great place to store your score. https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-state-component

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I modified it for gaze-based cursor, works perfectly!