# Make element visible on click event

Tags: aframe

I have a counter in my scene, using this code here: [A-frame score counter with multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108202/a-frame-score-counter-with-multiple-objects)

The object the user are clicking are are not visible (they are trying to guess where objects are in the scene). I would like them to become visible once they are clicked on.

I'm not sure how to get the item id from evt.target to change ('visible', true). Is there a way to get the id from evt.target so I can use document.querySelector? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the querySelector, the `evt.target` already has a valid reference to the clicked element:

```
this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
   e.target.setAttribute("visible", "true")
})
```

live fiddle [here](http://this.el.addEventListener(%22click%22,%20(e)=%3E%7B%20%20console.log(e.target)%20e.target.setAttribute(%22material%22,%20%22visible%22,%20%22false%22)%20%7D)).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use three.js to change visibility. Just use (objectname is name of your object)
`objname.visible = true.`